# Solr operator similar to reverse like operator in SQL

Tags: java, solr, wildcard

The documents in my Solr index have one field containing wildcards, e.g. `*smith`. I want to be able to query this field in a similar way as one would do with a reverse like operator in an SQL database.

For instance, in MySQL if I have a table called `names` with a column `wildcards` (wildcards containing wildcard characters as in `%smith`), I would be able to write `SELECT * FROM names where 'john smith' like wildcards` and get one result for the query.

Is this possible with Solr and ideally Solr Java API?

Comment: What area of the Java API do you imagine this would be happening?

Comment: I think It would be a custom function query